# Screen Flickering Issue on Incorrect Terminal Commands in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, flicker

After recently installing Ubuntu on my laptop, I've encountered an unusual issue. Every time I mistakenly enter an incorrect command in the terminal, my entire screen flickers momentarily. To help troubleshoot, here are the outputs of a few commands:

```
~ ❯ lshw -C display                                                 02:30:14 PM
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:181 memory:603c000000-603cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.



~ ❯ uname -a                                                  х INT 02:30:58 PM
Linux MyUsername-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i 6.2.0-32-generic #32~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 18 10:40:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


~ ❯ sudo dmesg | grep -i error                                                               02:32:56 PM
[    3.661270] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    6.131514] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[    6.131731] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    6.138073] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[    6.138136] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[ 1105.312048] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[ 1105.312064] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[ 1143.919053] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[ 1143.919074] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[23613.543170] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[23613.543192] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[23906.473648] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[23906.473669] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[28651.180424] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[28651.180445] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[75337.371041] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[75337.371066] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[113639.447928] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[113639.447945] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[118888.008497] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[118888.008514] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[119681.984012] gnome-shell[2152]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f2d09e92d87 sp 00007ffe5039feb0 error 4 in libst-1.0.so[7f2d09e6e000+4e000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)
[119690.980975] apport-gtk[12746]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fae2d18ccf4 sp 00007ffc570684e0 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2404.29[7fae2d084000+383000] likely on CPU 5 (core 1, socket 0)
[156363.342857] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[156363.342923] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[198555.511680] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[198555.511697] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[287340.445128] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[287340.445149] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[375400.480768] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[375400.480807] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[379921.707218] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[379921.707240] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[450791.072151] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[450791.072175] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[461293.046582] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[461293.046607] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[547494.697285] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[547494.697345] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[598077.829614] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[598077.829630] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[609402.134058] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[609402.134074] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[638689.705087] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[638689.705104] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[707855.487614] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[707855.487631] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[725518.276329] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[725518.276353] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[800483.558116] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[800483.558142] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[897018.762426] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[897018.762444] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[937744.104661] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.RP09.PEGP.DDNT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[937744.104684] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC.SEN4._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Please try close gnome-terminal and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell false`

Comment: @nobody thanks that worked. If you want to post that as an answer so it's more easier to discover the solution I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this flashing two gsettings key's are responsible.

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell false or true #this set or unset the behavior
org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell-type 'fullscreen-flash/frameflash'# set which kind of reaction.
```